# How find this $n$ such $p|\binom{n}{i}$

Tags: number-theory

Give a prime number $p$,Find all $n>0$ such that the binomial coffcients
$$\binom{n}{1},\binom{n}{2},\cdots,\binom{n}{n-1}$$
are all divisible by $p$.

My try:
since $$\binom{n}{i}=\dfrac{n}{(n-i)!i!}$$

Comment: Divisibility of $n$ by $p$ is not enough, for $\binom{6}{2}$ is not divisible by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

$n=k\cdot p$ ; otherwise $C_n^{1}=C_n^{n-1}=n$ will never be divisible through *p*.

Comment: $C_p^k$ is always divisible through *p* : this much is sure, for $k\neq0,p$ . And a non-multiple is out of the question. But which ones (apart from $n=p$) I don't know yet.

Answer (score 1):

Lucas's theorem (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem)) tells you the condition for $n \choose j$ to be divisible by $p$.  Now, what condition on $n$ will ensure that there is no
$j \in \{1,2,\ldots, n-1\}$ whose base $p$ digits are all $\le$ the corresponding base $p$ digit for $n$?